# View Data Per Day MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm making a simple application about the daily assessment test of employees in the office.

The application stores the score results of several daily questions in the database, daily questions are inputted every day.

I have 2 tables in my MySQL Database, there is:

1. **account_table**
2. **assessment_table**

This is account_table :

```
accountID | accountName | accountEmail  
        1 | John        | john@example.com 
        2 | Derick      | derick@example.com
        3 | Ratna       | ratna@example.com
```

And this is assessment_table: (for example today is 2020-10-08)

```
     assessmentID  |  accountID    |  assessmentScore | assessmentDate
      1            |   1           |  50              | 2020-10-07
      2            |   2           |  75              | 2020-10-07
      3            |   3           |  93              | 2020-10-07
      4            |   2           |  47              | 2020-10-08
      5            |   3           |  80              | 2020-10-08
```

How can I see accounts that haven't done an assessment today?
Thank you for your help, Regards.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT act.*
FROM account_table act
LEFT JOIN assessment_table ast ON act.accountID = ast.accountID 
                              AND ast.assessmentDate = '2020-10-08'
WHERE ast.accountID IS NULL
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM account_table act
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
                   FROM assessment_table ast 
                   WHERE act.accountID = ast.accountID 
                     AND ast.assessmentDate = '2020-10-08' )
```

You may use `CURRENT_DATE` instead of `'2020-10-08'` literal for to receive the output for current day always.

PS. I do not show `WHERE NOT IN` variant - it is slower in almost all cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM account_table WHERE account_table.accountID NOT IN (
    SELECT accounts.accountID
    FROM assessment_table assessments
    INNER JOIN account_table accounts ON assessments.accountID = accounts.accountID
    WHERE assessments.assessmentDate = "2020-10-08"
)
```

Comment: How would you parse that result?

Comment: What's the reason to use one more `account_table` in subquery?

Comment: @Akina Over the time I had to use subquery lots of time, so did same here. Actually I am not so expert yet and just wanted to take part here. Your answer seems the best. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This sql statement should work

```
SELECT account_table.accountID 
FROM account_table 
WHERE account_table.accountID NOT IN
(SELECT assessment_table.accountID 
FROM assessment_table 
WHERE CAST(assessmentDate AS DATE) = CAST("2020-10-08" AS DATE))
```

"2020-10-08" you could use functions like NOW() to get all entries of today

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
SELECT ac_t.* FROM `account_table` ac_t
INNER JOIN `assessment_table` as_t
ON ac_t.accountID = as_t.accountID
WHERE as_t.accountID NOT IN (
    SELECT accountID FROM assessment_table WHERE `assessmentDate` = '2020-10-08'
    )
```

If you want today not hardcoded

```
SELECT ac_t.* FROM `account_table` ac_t
INNER JOIN `assessment_table` as_t
ON ac_t.accountID = as_t.accountID
WHERE as_t.accountID NOT IN (
    SELECT accountID FROM assessment_table WHERE `assessmentDate` = CURDATE()
    )
```

Comment: What's the reason to use one more `assessment_table` in main query?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM account_table 
WHERE accountID NOT IN (SELECT accountID FROM assessment_table WHERE assessmentDate = DATE(NOW()));
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the below command if some extra entries present in the assessment_table which do not have an entry in the account table will be rejected.

```
SELECT * FROM account_table 
WHERE accountID NOT IN 
(SELECT assessment_table.accountID FROM assessment_table 
 RIGHT JOIN account_table on account_table.accountID = assessment_table.accountID 
 WHERE assessment_table.assessmentDate = DATE(NOW()))
```

Comment: What's the reason to use one more `account_table` in subquery?

Comment: to reject the null value in the sub query

Comment: What NULL do you mean, in what column of what table? Example source does not contain NULLs. And generally `assessment_table.accountID` must be FK and NOT NULL (by its meaning).

Comment: Foreign key column can have null values.

Comment: FOREIGN KEY column which is defined as NOT NULL cannot have null values.

Comment: these constraints were not defined in asked question.

Comment: This is the reason why I tell "generally", not "always" or "in the question".

Comment: it depends upon the situation, query will differ with situation.

Answer (score -2):

hi Please use this sql statement

```
  $today = date("d");
    $month = date('m');
    $year  = date('Y');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM account_table as account inner join assessment_table as on account.accountID=assesment.accountId  where DAY(assesment.assessmentDate) = $today AND MONTH(assesment.assessmentDate) = $month AND YEAR(assesment.assessmentDate) = $year";
```

Comment: Please don't use this statement

Comment: @Strawberry can you please come with some explanation?

Comment: There are many. First, see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries.

Comment: mean less reply